# AngularJS cannot grab values with ng-model while using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to grab dynamically created information with ng-model (info created with ng-repeat). I am doing so in order to send the information in the form of an object to my flat database, Firebase. Unfortunately, the ng-model is only grabbing "" (empty strings) as my values. Any suggestions?

```js
/////////// Controller below

 // Bookmark object
 $scope.bookmark = {
  url: "",
  illnessName: "",
  symptom: ""
 };

 // Save illness card to bookmarks
 $scope.saveToBookmarks = ($bookmark) => {
  console.log($bookmark);

  if ($scope.bookmark.illnessName === ""){
   alert("Hey, quit that NAME!");
   return;
  }
  if ($scope.bookmark.symptom === ""){
   alert("Hey, quit that SYMPTOM!");
   return;
  }
  if ($scope.bookmark.url === ""){
   alert("Hey, quit that URL!");
   return;
  }


  BookmarksFactory.addUserBookmark({
   url: $scope.bookmark.url,
   illnessName: $scope.bookmark.illnessName,
   symptom: $scope.bookmark.symptom
  });
  console.log("$scope.bookmark.url :",  $scope.bookmark.url);
 };
  
  
  
  
  ///////// Factory below
  "use strict";

app.factory("BookmarksFactory", function(FBCreds, $q, $http) {

 var addUserBookmark = (newBookmark) =>{
  console.log("Factory is working!");
  return $q( (resolve, reject) => {
   $http.post(`${FBCreds.databaseURL}/bookmarks.json`,
    JSON.stringify(newBookmark))
   .then( (FBObj) => {
    resolve(FBObj);
   })
   .catch( (error) => {
    reject(error);
   });
  });
 };

 return {
  addUserBookmark
 };

});
```

```html
  <!-- This will be search results populate --> 
  <div class="search-results" >
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 text-center search-card box" ng-repeat="illness in illnesses | filter: searchText.search">
     <!-- Insert search results here -->
     <div class="inner ">
      <div class="card">
       <button type="button" class="close close-card" aria-label="Close" ng-click="removeCard($event)">
         <span class="close-card-x" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
       </button>
       <img class="card-img-top" src="{{illness.url}}" alt="Card image cap" ng-model="bookmark.url">
       <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title" ng-model="bookmark.illnessName">{{illness.illnessName}}</h4>
        <p class="card-text" ng-model="bookmark.symptom">{{illness.symptom}}</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveToBookmarks(bookmark)">Save</button>
        <a href="#!/edit-illness/{{illness.id}}"><button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="goToEditPage()">Edit</button></a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change  to `$scope.bookmark ={};`
and use http to get data file you code , example of me is test.php

```
$http(){
           method:'POST',
           url:'test.php',
           data : $.param($scope.bookmark), 
           headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
                }).then(success)
function success(){
////
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the response!